# Android nanohttpd doesn't start properly

Tags: android, nanohttpd

I need httpd server in my app, so I've choose NanoHttpd.

I've subclassed my own server:

```
public class StreamingServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    private Context mContext;
    public StreamingServer(Context context) {
        super(8080);
        mContext = context;
        Log.i("MyServer", "Streaming server created");
    }
```

And I'm trying to launch my server in main activity:

```
       // onCreate:
       server = new StreamingServer(getApplicationContext());
```

Here is my onResume method:

```
        // onResume:
        super.onResume();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "exception!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "started!");
```

and onPause:

```
        super.onPause();
        if (server != null) {
             server.stop();
             Log.i(TAG, "stopped!");
        }
```

I've also done proper setup:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

So I believe I've done everything right. But launching my app leads to nothing (Page are unavailable). Some how 2 or 3 launches leads to server launch (and I do NOTHING different at that moment).

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

NanoHttpd expects you to override the "serve()" method.  The response object that you return from your overridden method will be returned to the web browser that hits your server.  The "README" document on the github site has a fully functioning example (https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) that returns debug information to the browser.

If you want to serve more interesting content, look at the samples/ folder inside the NanoHttpd project, or the webserver/ folder for a fully functional web server.